# Python retrieve JSON from mysql TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not tuple

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

When I attempt to retrieve `JSON` from `MYSQL` why does it comes with this error? How do I solve this?

`def get_go(order_no):

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT `order_details` FROM `orders` WHERE `order_no` = " + str(order_no))

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    return json.loads(x)`
```

It returns with this error.

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py", line 341, in loads
> raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, ' TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not
> tuple

When I tried to do the same using

```
x = 'my_json_data_here'
y = json.loads(x)
```

it works fine. Why?

Comment: How do you get the part tagged `my_json_data_here` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reasons why.

Why using this method to retrieve JSON, the data comes with a (' json_data ',)
which is not an valid json. I don't know why. But I made some changes to retrieving data from mysql
connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
and it works it comes with the values without (' ',)

Comment: I got the same error. I am trying to fix this with the solution you provided above but it's not working.

Comment: @Priyasingh it's not pretty but you can always attach another [0] to extract the first element of a tuple. json.loads(x[0])